# jQuery / Regex pattern: only allow digits an one comma

Tags: jquery, regex

Here's my pattern:

```
var regex = /^[0-9\b,]+$/;
```

I'm having a currency textbox and only want to allow numbers and ONE comma, so eg.
123456,789 should result in 123.456,789

Comment: Why should `123456,789` result in `123.456,789`? What's stipulating that there should be three sets of numbers before the dot? ...are you sure you wouldn't benefit from a money formatter instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply trying to verify that the input is comprised of digits and (at most) a single comma, you can use

```
var regex = /^[0-9]+,?[0-9]+$/
```

This will match patterns that have one or more digits, followed by zero or one comma, followed by one or more digits.  It places no restrictions on how many digits are allowed on either side of the comma and doesn't allow periods.

Comment: unfortunately your regex seems to accept nothing at all :/